# How to add class in existing class given element JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a new class to a given class without using GetElementById. My project has an array on the list, and each list creates dynamic classes like 0-test, 1-test, 2-testing, so on. Add a new class to a given class like ( 0-test active-test) class. I am trying to have some javascript properties, but it is not working properly. My code is:-

```
document.getElementsByClassName('0-test')[0].className += "active-test";
```

It's not working please tell me how to add a new class?

Comment: There should be a space in `"active-test"` like `" active-test"` otherwise it will get appended to some other class (probably resulting in `"0-testactive-test"`). BTW, it's better to use `classList` for this instead of `className`: `.classList.add("active-test");`

Comment: Better to use `document.querySelector` if you only want the first matching element.

Comment: I have already use document.querySelector('.0-test').className += " active-test"; But its return error in because classes generate dynamically in run time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.classList`:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('0-test')[0];
element.classList.add("mystyle");
```

Comment: This code working on first two array elements, another elements is not working.

Comment: use document.querySelectorAll to get all the elements and then add a class to all these elements.